# Hibernate second level caching

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, caching

Can I use second level cache in Hibernate for caching query (**createSQLQuery**) like:

```
List<Student> books = (List<Student>)session.createSQLQuery("select * from Student ");
```

Can I use second level cache in Hibernate for caching query (**createQuery**) like:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where studentId = :id ");
query.setParameter("id", 5);
List<Student> list = query.list();
```

If "YES",  what ***cache.provider_class*** can I use? (`SingletonEhCacheProvider` is deprecated in Hibernate 4.3.8).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hibernate second level cache in your application , so you need some changes in `hibernat.cfg.xml` file. 
In `<session-factory>` tag put

`<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>`

`<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>`
 And most importantly put `<cache usage=”read-write” />` in your every entity's `hbm.xml` file after `<id>` tag . 
that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "query cache" with createQuery ! you have to add setCacheable(true) to your HQL query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where studentId = :id ");
query.setParameter("id", 5).setCacheable(true);
```

you can use [this configuraion](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-hib_enable_second_level_cache_settings.html) (hibernate 4.3.8)

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

This worked for me